# Pie chart using Charts library with swift

Tags: ios, charts, swift3, core-graphics, pie-chart

I am integrating pie chart in my app using [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library and getting issue with chart data my code is

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var pieChartView: PieChartView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]
    let unitsSold = [10.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0]
    setChart(dataPoints: months, values: unitsSold)
  }

  func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
      let dataEntry1 = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i], data: dataPoints[i] as AnyObject)
      dataEntries.append(dataEntry1)
    }
    print(dataEntries[0].data)
    let pieChartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    let pieChartData = PieChartData(dataSet: pieChartDataSet)
    pieChartView.data = pieChartData
    
    var colors: [UIColor] = []
    
    for _ in 0..<dataPoints.count {
      let red = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
      let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
      let blue = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        
      let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)
      colors.append(color)
    }
    pieChartDataSet.colors = colors
  }
}
```

and when run app I getting something this
[image]

but I need pie chart in full data records like in below screen shot
[image]

Comment: both are same ? and ya if you want to print month name with your valye in chart then just add it with your value means append your text value when its go to build chart

Comment: I have already append text value initialise time in this line:  let dataEntry1 = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i], data: dataPoints[i] as AnyObject)

Comment: Using code from appcoda: https://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/

Comment: just print your append data dataEntry1

Comment: @Himanshu, I have print data and getting corresponding values.

Comment: if you append data before chart init then why should its not display on chart ?

Comment: @RajJoshi You question helped me out and saved a lot of time Thanks Mate! Voted up

Comment: @Raghav Thanks for your attention!

Comment: using chart in what install name is  in podfile for xcode 8.3 and swift 3.1

Comment: Hello actually I used pod 'Charts' same as

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason all the information isn't showing up is because you are using a parent initialiser when creating the entry point.

Instead of

```
let dataEntry1 = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i], data: dataPoints[i] as AnyObject)
```

try this instead

```
let dataEntry1 = PieChartDataEntry(value: Double(i), label: dataPoints[i], data:  dataPoints[i] as AnyObject)
```

The PieChartDataEntry is specifically for Pie charts so you should see the month show up in the chart.

Hopefully this gets you on the right track

Answer (score 35):

> Update for this question.

```
  func updateChartData()  {

    let chart = PieChartView(frame: self.view.frame)
    // 2. generate chart data entries
    let track = ["Income", "Expense", "Wallet", "Bank"]
    let money = [650, 456.13, 78.67, 856.52]

    var entries = [PieChartDataEntry]()
    for (index, value) in money.enumerated() {
        let entry = PieChartDataEntry()
        entry.y = value
        entry.label = track[index]
        entries.append( entry)
    }

    // 3. chart setup
    let set = PieChartDataSet( values: entries, label: "Pie Chart")
    // this is custom extension method. Download the code for more details.
    var colors: [UIColor] = []

    for _ in 0..<money.count {
        let red = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let blue = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)
        colors.append(color)
    }
    set.colors = colors
    let data = PieChartData(dataSet: set)
    chart.data = data
    chart.noDataText = "No data available"
    // user interaction
    chart.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let d = Description()
    d.text = "iOSCharts.io"
    chart.chartDescription = d
    chart.centerText = "Pie Chart"
    chart.holeRadiusPercent = 0.2
    chart.transparentCircleColor = UIColor.clear
    self.view.addSubview(chart)

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to show percentage sign with digits?

Comment: how can I assign JSON array to piechart?